# Scheduled Task, fails to set as expected

Tags: batch-file

I tried to execute a windows batch to create a scheduled task on a remote machine by passing remote user id and password, but it throws out the below error:

> WARNING: The scheduled task "Appchecks" has been created, but may not run because the account information could not be set.

Batch command:

```
SchTasks /Create /S remotePC /U uid /P pwd /RU ruid /RP rpwd /SC ONCE /TN "Appchecks" /TR "batch.bat" /ST 23:00 /F
```

I can see that the scheduled task has been created, along with user id set, but password is not getting set.

Also, I am using a separate file that has the password that I supply to this command. The password is entered one character per line and the character is in ascii code in the file. In the main script I am reading the file, converting the ascii chars to normal and appending together to get the correct password and then using it in the create scheduled task command. Have tried with giving the password directly in the command as well. Both the ways am getting the same error.

Please assist.

Comment: As the password is no doubt the only piece of information you should not be telling us here, _(theres no reason why the PC or user names cannot be divulged)_, you may need to enclose your password in doublequotes. It is likely that it contains one or more 'poison' characters, _which cause problems when unquoted_.

Comment: Right, I was using a separate file that has the password. The password is entered one character per line and the character is in ascii code in the file.

In the main script I am reading the file, converting the ascii chars to normal and appending to gether to get the correct password and then using it in the create scheduled task command

Comment: Well it appears that the reason for your issue is all of the stuff you haven't added to your question. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54983504/edit) function to revisit your question area and rewrite it so that we have all of the relevant information in one place.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question, however, this is not a guessing game. Your provided output states that the issue is with the account information, but all of that information is what is missing from your question. We need to see the code that you are using to read the text file, convert each line to the respective characters, and create the password variable. We also need to see the exact command you're using, complete with the names/variables/passwords etc. If you do not provide that information, your question will be closed as, in its current state, it is too broad and not reproducible.

Comment: That is not the issue. Pls do not divert if you aren't sure of the issue. I have clearly stated I have tried giving the password directly and with reading from file as described earlier. There should be something else that causes this error. May be due to some permission or privilege related.

Comment: Have you read the usage information resulting from the following command `SchTasks /Create /?` and are you sure that you've provided all of the correct information for the command to work according to its output? If you are then the problem can only be that you are providing the incorrect password, or the password you are using has one or more characters which, in your current syntax, are problematic. Your choice is simple, either implement the advice I've given, or delete your question taking it to a platform where helpers are happy to be treated like they're less knowledgeable than you!

Comment: If you have sufficient privileges to create the task, _which you've already shown us you have, (because it has been created)_, the issue must be with the data attached to `/RU` and/or to `/RP`. We cannot help you with either of those pieces of information as we don't know all of your correct user names on `remotePC`, if `remotePC` exists, and as you have both omitted the password, and not shown us the method you're using to create/retrieve it, that data either. I've provided the only help I can give in my opening comment, and that was to enclose those pieces of information within doublequotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, and is simply a two line example of a method of reading ASCII character codes from each line of a text file and converting them to their respective characters to create the password.

*Text file **(Pwd.txt)**:*

```
80
97
115
115
119
111
114
100
```

*Batch file **(GetPwd.cmd)**:*

```bat
@Set "pwd="&For /F UseBackQ %%A In ("Pwd.txt")Do @Cmd/C "Exit/B %%A"&Call Set "pwd=%%pwd%%%%=ExitCodeAscii%%"
@If Defined pwd Echo("%pwd%"&Pause
```

If you're happy with the output of the batch file, you can replace line `2` with your `SchTasks /Create` command, remembering to enclose your strings in doublequotes and obviously change the name/path of the text file you're reading your password data from.

I see no reason why you couldn't have provided information similar to the above as part of your question. You could have even provided the real password, because without access to your specific network/PC and without its genuine username it is of absolutely no use to us, and does not as such divulge 'sensitive' information!